# Converting .LAS to .PCD file using CloudCompare

Tags: las, cloudcompare, pcd

I want to convert a LAS file to PCD format using CloudCompare software. How I can do that?

Comment: So why did you tag this with ArcGIS 10.6 if CloudCompare is an open-source project?

Comment: @vince  He (Mazin) didn't say which software he was uisng the las file...?

Comment: Mazin   - so how did you use the LAS file from which software did you use with ?

Answer (score 0):

Latest stable release (2.10.2 Zephyrus) supports the Point Cloud Libary format (.pcd).
Load the LAS file, hit the Save Button and select .pcd.
But it looks like there are some problems with saving point clouds that have a high point count.

Comment: But it doesn't preserve coordinates, this is causing me a problem.

Comment: Sher - https://www.danielgm.net/cc/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3805